# How to create custom 404 error page in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

Is it possible to create a custom error page and also that page will be manage through back-end in WordPress.

WordPress provided a 404.php default but I want to create a custom 404 page that can be managed through back end also **(I want to create it without using any plugin)**.

Comment: create a `404.php` in your theme's directory root and WordPress will use it. If you want to manage the 404 page's content in admin, then you should create a `theme options` page or a `settings page`. There are many ways to do this. Either do it yourself from scratch or use a plugin like Advanced Custom Fields.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a template file 404.php in your themes root folder, wordpress will then use this to route all 404 errors.

Refer for more information:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_an_Error_404_Page

Answer (score 1):

You can manage the custom 404 page from admin without any plugin:

**Step One:**

Create page for 404 from backend & copy the page URL

**Step Two**

Open you `.htaccess` and add the following

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://yourwebsite.com/error-404
```

Update the URL to your 404 page you created in step one

Comment: i already tried this option but still page showing result of default 404.php file.

Comment: remove the 404.php or rename that 404.php.stop

Comment: Just noticed that was  for '401'  error code corrected to '404'

Answer (score 0):

Create a file '404.php' in your theme's root folder, WordPress uses this file to handle 404 errors.
For more reference visit this official link - https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_an_Error_404_Page